# How to hide the master view if navigate to new view controller from detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to hide view if user click on button in details view controller to push new VC

I tried this line work when push new view put when pop view the master never appear

```
self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.primaryHidden
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question accordingly to provide more information since you do not have a lot of information provided. We don't know your view set up, or the navigation flow. Please provide more information to help us provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the `preferredDisplayMode` back to normal when you pop the detail view controller?